# org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer spamming Logfile

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-axis

We have a Tomcat application that uses the Axis2 library, which comes bundled in the WAR-File. In the application-specific logfile I see a lot of this messages (about 5 times per incoming request):

```
2015-07-28 09:50:17,666 INFO  [http-8443-3] org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer: Deploying module: addressing - file:/srv/tomcat/webapps/MyApp/WEB-INF/lib/axis2-1.4.1.jar
2015-07-28 09:50:17,766 INFO  [http-8443-3] org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer: Deploying module: addressing - file:/srv/tomcat/webapps/MyApp/WEB-INF/lib/axis2-1.4.1.jar
2015-07-28 09:50:17,867 INFO  [http-8443-3] org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer: Deploying module: addressing - file:/srv/tomcat/webapps/MyApp/WEB-INF/lib/axis2-1.4.1.jar
2015-07-28 09:50:17,966 INFO  [http-8443-3] org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer: Deploying module: addressing - file:/srv/tomcat/webapps/MyApp/WEB-INF/lib/axis2-1.4.1.jar
2015-07-28 09:50:18,066 INFO  [http-8443-3] org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer: Deploying module: addressing - file:/srv/tomcat/webapps/MyApp/WEB-INF/lib/axis2-1.4.1.jar
2015-07-28 09:50:18,412 INFO  [http-8443-7] org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer: Deploying module: addressing - file:/srv/tomcat/webapps/MyApp/WEB-INF/lib/axis2-1.4.1.jar
2015-07-28 09:50:18,513 INFO  [http-8443-7] org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer: Deploying module: addressing - file:/srv/tomcat/webapps/MyApp/WEB-INF/lib/axis2-1.4.1.jar
2015-07-28 09:50:18,612 INFO  [http-8443-7] org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer: Deploying module: addressing - file:/srv/tomcat/webapps/MyApp/WEB-INF/lib/axis2-1.4.1.jar
2015-07-28 09:50:18,713 INFO  [http-8443-7] org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer: Deploying module: addressing - file:/srv/tomcat/webapps/MyApp/WEB-INF/lib/axis2-1.4.1.jar
2015-07-28 09:50:18,814 INFO  [http-8443-7] org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer: Deploying module: addressing - file:/srv/tomcat/webapps/MyApp/WEB-INF/lib/axis2-1.4.1.jar
```

Now, I have no knowledge of axis2 and only little about Tomcat. However, the log message sounds to me like this jar file is being loaded over and over again (which usually is a bad thing).

**My Questions**

- 1 - What does this message actually mean?
- 2 - Is it a bad thing that this is in my logfile that often?

  - 2a - If yes, what can I do about it?
  - 2b - If no, can I get rid of the message?